# write to existing XML file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest

So here is the task.
I have an existing XML file that is located in my public dropbox folder.

[Link to XML File](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4171179/testValues.xml)

And I know how to read values from the XML file by following the following tutorial

[link to tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_list_loop)

and changing 2 rows to the following

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4171179/testValues.xml");

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("growth");
```

But how can I write to that file? Say that I want to change the

```
<growth>1.25</growth>
```

To

```
<growth>1.05</growth>
```

How can this be done, is it even possible?

Regards

Anders

Answer (score 0):

For all I know Javascript is not allowed to write to any files (local HDD or server). This for security reasons. So the best thing you can do is make an Ajax call to your server and make the changes from there in your XML file.

I suggest that you use Ajax because then you don't have to refresh the page all the time. You can take a look at Jquery for a very fast and easy way to make an ajax call.

What kind of server are you running your website on? Apache (PHP) or Windows(.NET)?

**EDIT**:
**Just a quick JQuery ajax call for sample.**

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST", 
    url: "some.php", 
    data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

And then on the server (PHP)

```
<?php
   $growth_post = $_POST["growth"]; 
   ... code to handle the data ...

   $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
   $doc->load("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4171179/testValues.xml");
   $items = $doc->getElementsByTagName("data"); 

   foreach( $items as $item ) {
        $growth = $item->getElementsByTagName("growth"); 
        $growth->item(0)->nodeValue = $growth_post;
    }
    $doc->save("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4171179/testValues.xml")
?>
```

But you have to be sure that you have write privileges on the dropbox file!